# Append/Insert detail records (NestedDataSet) in DataSetProvider OnUpdateData

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-2010, dbexpress

I would like to insert detail records in an `OnUpdateData` event of the `DataSetProvider` and have the changes updated to the database along with the master record.

What is the best way to achieve this.

I have tried inserting records to the `NestedDataSet` but they are not sent to the database along with the delta.

Using Delphi 7 or Delphi 2010 with MySQL and dbexpress:

```
Master: InvoicePayment (SQLDataSet, DataSetProvider, ClientDataSet)
Detail: InvoicePaymentLine (NestedDataSet)
```

The user inputs payment amounts and the program loops through `Delta` in an `OnUpdateData` event processing invoices to be paid and inserts them in the detail table (`InvoicePaymentLine`) for each master record.

I would prefer not to use `BeforeUpdateRecord` event but instead process all records at once in a loop.

Comment: After researching on this, I have found out that you can append data packets manually to a DataSet by calling the AppendData method.  Any ideas on how I can implement the above to insert records in an OnUpdateData event handler and send them to the Database along with the previous delta.